# Does standard App Engine send a mail automatically to the admin if the app is out of capacity?

Tags: google-app-engine, notifications

For example, if an instance uses too much memory, or due to the max instance limit no new instance can be started, or the app goes over some other limit due to too much traffic.

In those case does App Engine notify the admin automatically?

Or is it the app admin's job to keep an eye on the app and notice if it's overloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no automatic way to do that with Google App Engine only.

However, you have the option to use Stackdriver in order to set alerts to be notified whenever some metrics exceed a threshold that you've set up. To do so:

- Navigate to `Monitoring > Alerting`
- Click on "Create policy" at the top of the page
- Under the Add Condition button you can select `GAE_APP` as resource and then the Metrics you want to watch.
- You can also edit the notification channels at the `Monitoring > Alerting` dashboard.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui) you will be able to find all the documentation on who to create Alerts.
 The full list of metrics available for Google App Engine can also be found in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-appengine).

Comment: Thanks. So that means if the app is out of memory,etc. then no Stackdriver error is generated at all? Does App Engine just swallow these errors?

Comment: You will see different logs in Stackdriver depending on what is causing the error. If those are server side, HTTP 500s will be the ones appearing most likely. If you wish to have more specific data of what is happening, then `Stackdriver Monitoring` is what you are looking for as the metrics being exceeded will show there and are easier to track.

Comment: OK, I asked, because if an error goes to Stackdriver Error Reporting (so not logs, but errors)  then App Engine does send an automatic notification if you turn it on. I just didn't see it documented if server errors go there or not.

Comment: Stackdriver Error Reporting has a notification service in beta now, you can give it a try, check the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/notifications). With this alongside Monitoring you will have full coverage of the errors happening to your app. I think Monitoring it's better to keep an eye on metrics such as CPU and Error Reporting to watch the rest of errors happening on the application. Of course, this all depends on your use case and what you would like to achieve.